# Derive momentum from fluid pressure

Tags: pressure

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the velocity of fluid in a pipe due to the pressure acting on it.

My basic understanding is that Pascal's Principle says a fluid under pressure will effectively transmit that pressure to all parts of itself.  So if a wine bottle is under pressure of 10 N/m2 then the force on the cork is 10 N, assuming an unrealistic surface area of a square meter.  And so the acceleration, velocity and momentum of the cork will only depend on the pressure.

But I don't understand what happens in the scenario where the wine bottle now has 2 openings with a cork in each.  Each cork has the same pressure, and so they both have that full 10 N of force and the same acceleration.  I know from real life that their momentum won't be the same though and of course that would violate energy conservation.

All I can think of is I am missing out on factoring time into all of this, because velocity does depend on time.  But I can't see how you work out that the time or momentum somehow gets split between the two corks evenly?

Answer (score 0):

Pascal's principle is only valid for fluids at rest. If you have flow through a pipe, a pressure gradient is required to overcome the wall shear stress.